# GreenRobot EventBus crash app

Tags: android, greenrobot-eventbus

I use [GreenRobot's EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) all over my app and love it. When I use a method like

```
public void onEventMainThread(SearchStartedEvent e) {

    doThis();

}
```

and in `doThis()` there is an Exception like a NPE, the App won't crash but EventBus will Log.e() the exception. Can I configure EventBus so it will actually crash my App? That would make debugging easier for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instance of SubscriberExceptionEvent is posted by EventBus when an exception occurs inside a subscriber's event handling method. You can implement method

```
public void onEvent(SubscriberExceptionEvent exceptionEvent) {
     yourHandlingMethod(exceptionEvent.throwable);
}
```

and handle any thrown exception.